# Kafka Connect - filter fields in value by regex

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to remove fields from a message value if they match a regex, e.g. `/^__before_.+$/`

original:

```json
{
   "count": 5,
   "bags": 42,
   "__before_count": 4,
   "__before_bags": 19
}
```

desired:

```json
{
   "count": 5,
   "bags": 42,
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to filter fields is with a hard coded list, e.g., with the [ReplaceField transformation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html).

Is it possible to define a regex to filter out fields?

Comment: Wouldn't it ignoring those fields whenever processing the message be ok? Not sure if there is a good reason to add extra processing on a message just to ignore fields.

Comment: @JorgeCampos the transformation would be happening for a sink connector, ideally these fields will not be propagated to the database.

Comment: So, to basically save space then. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

With built-in transforms, there is not, you need to [write your own](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html) or find an external transform project that does it.

Comment: thanks! Beyond redhat & jcustenborder, are there any good external transformation projects to check out?

Comment: I think Jeremy's are pretty good. Not really familiar with others